# É possivel trocar classe de muitas DIVs com um unico comando js?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Amigos
Tenho diversas DIVs em minha pagina, cada qual com seu ID, porem com o mesmo padrao, por exemplo "checker-001", "checker-002", e asim por diante...
onde, eu uso um JS para trocar suas caracteristicas, por exemplo

```
$('#checker-363').removeClass('UmaVelhaClass').addClass('UmaNovaClass');
```

que eh bastante simples e util.

**Eis minha pergunta**:
É possivel trocar centenas de DIVs de uma soh vez? com um único comando?
por exemplo trocando o "numero" por um   " * ":

```
 $('#checker-*').removeClass('UmaVelhaClasse').addClass('UmaNovaClasse');
```

Ou sou obrigado a fazer um loop pra isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilize isso:

```
$('[id^="checker-"]').removeClass('UmaVelhaClasse').addClass('UmaNovaClasse');
```

Quando você utiliza o seletor `[id^="checker-"]` você está buscando todos os elementos que possuem o id que iniciam com aquele padrão, no caso `checker-`.

Comment: rapaizzz , muito obrigado por ser tao objetivo e responder EXATAMENTE  a minha pergunta!  ajudou demais!!!

Comment: Nada, é um prazer ajudar

Comment: Ahh sim .. detalhe, esqueci de agradecer o **codigo** de exemplo **funcionando**!  pra gente que eh noob e nem sabe fazer a pergunta direito, ele eh parte **essencial** !!!!!!!!!!!! Valeu mais uma vez!

Answer (score 3):

Experimente adicionar uma `classe` em comum para todas as divs que deseja alterar, uma vez que você quer fazer troca de `classe` em todas de uma só vez, não acho recomendado seleciona-las por `id` já que todas possuem essa necessidade em comum. O uso do seletor `[id^="checker-"]` resolve o problema, porém, ele é um pouco mais pesado.

Um exemplo de uso seria:
`$('.classeEmComum').removeClass('UmaVelhaClasse').addClass('UmaNovaClasse');`